# jquery- add to input value from table td

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Each time the user clicks on cells of a table, i want add the text of the cell to an inputbox. here is my code

search is my input ID.

Example is my Table ID.

```
$('#example td').click(function(evt) {
    var name = $('#search').val()+$(this).text();
    $('#search').val(name);  
});
```

everytime i click on a cell i only get it's text in the input and the input's previous value disappears. how i can fix it?

I have another problem and for example if the cell's text is `"david"` i will get the string `"          david         "` with spaces. Is there anyway to get `td` text without spaces?

Comment: Your code should work (after fixing your braces), it's better if you put more information about your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
$('#example td').click(function() {
    $('#search').val( $.trim($('#search').val()) + $.trim($(this).text()) )
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong, the code has more `}`

Correct:

```
$('#example td').click(function(evt) {

var name = $('#search').val()+$(this).text();

   $('#search').val(name);  
});
```

And the code works well for me: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EQ47Q/1/)